# Entity Framework validation fails on unused property update

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have a problem that I can't seem to understand, let alone solve. Any help would be appreciated.

So I have an MVC application, Entity Framework, the usual. I have a request that can update one property of one entity. This request sends the Id of the entity and the new value of the property.

In order to avoid querying the database for the entity, and since I only want to do the update on that one property and then return, I attach a new entity to the context with the id and then set the `CurrentValue`. Something like this:

```
public class MyEntityHandler
{
   // dbContext is my EF context, instantiated from a DI container
   // ...
   public void UpdateProperty<TProp>(MyEntity entity, Expression<Func<MyEntity , TProp>> property, TProp value)
   {
      var memberName=(property.Body as MemberExpression).Member.Name;
      var temp = dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<MyEntity>()
                          .SingleOrDefault( o => o.Entity.Id == entity.Id );
      if( temp == null || temp.State == EntityState.Detached) 
      {
        dbContext.MyEntities.Attach( entity );                              
      }         
      this.dbContext.Entry(entity).Property(memberName).IsModified = true;
      this.dbContext.Entry(entity).Property(memberName).CurrentValue = value;               
   }
}
```

Then, this can be used like this: `UpdateProperty(e, e=>e.Prop, "NewValue")`;
where `e` is of type `MyEntity`, and `Prop` is a string property in it.
When the post request comes in, I simply create a new `MyEntity`, I assign the id and then call this method. Something like this (there are a couple more layers, but it makes no difference for my question):

```
public ActionResult MyMethod(int id, string newValue)
{
  var e=new MyEntity { MyEntityId=id };
  new MyEntityHandler().UpdateProperty(e,e=>e.Prop,newValue);
  return View();
}
```

My understanding is that in this case, EF should attach the entity in unchanged state. The entity in my case is not in the context and the attach succeeds. Then I update that one single property, which will put the entity into `Modified` state, so an update statement should be generated on `SaveChanges()`. Since only the one property is changed, that should be the only one in the update statement. I double checked the values in the `ChangeTracker`, I can see that the entity is modified and the property is modified, but every other property i not modified.

The problem is that when I call `SaveChanges()`, I get a `DbValidationException`, because one of the other properties is null, but it has  a `Required` attribute. This is all rightfully so - since I attach a new entity and set only the id before attaching, it should be null. I just don't understand the validation error - I'm not trying to insert that value into the database (again, I checked the ChangeTracker and the state of the entity is modified and the property in question is not modified).

Why do I get this validation error? Is this by design? Is there a way to tell EF to let this save through (without disabling the validation altogerher on the context)?